# How to send a variables of the calendar class via Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

A variables of the calendar class isn't String. 
I want to know how to pass time variable values ​​to the board using Via Bluetooth. 
pickerTime is a TimePicker in actitvity_main.xml
 , buttonSetAlarm is a button to set alarm

This is the source:

```
        pickerTime.setCurrentMinute(now.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        ///------------------------ALARM
        buttonSetAlarm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setalarm);
        buttonSetAlarm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(pickerDate.getYear(),
                        pickerDate.getMonth(),
                        pickerDate.getDayOfMonth(),
                        pickerTime.getCurrentHour(),
                        pickerTime.getCurrentMinute(),00);

                if(cal.compareTo(current) <= 0){
                    //The set Date/Time already passed
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Invalid Date/Time",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    setAlarm(cal);

                }

            }});
```

This is send data method via bluetooth

```
public void setSendData(String sendData) {
            byte[] magBuffer = sendData.getBytes();
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(magBuffer);

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }
```

Please,help me because I don't know how to pass the time value. 
and Thank you.

Comment: Which type is the data you want to send?

Comment: I want to send integer. Can it be sent?

Comment: you can see that you are sending `byte[]` in fact, not the `String`. Just convert integer to `byte[]`, and send. Or convert it to `String`, and send. It depends on how the recipient expects it.

Comment: I appreciate your help. And I would like to know what  ` cal `  type is ?
I'm not sure about to sent the variable value.

Comment: I can't convert variable. It can't be applied to(java.util.Calendar)

Comment: `java.util.Calendar` obviously is a type. There is a way to send it, but believe me, it is not what you want. It is still unclear what exactly you want to send.

Comment: Can it be converted from `java.util.Calendar`?

Comment: `It is still unclear what exactly you want to send`

Comment: Sorry , I asked not to clear myself.